# Anomaly in python with matrix multiplication

Tags: python, matrix, vector

I have the following function:

```
def logistic(y):
    print((1-y).shape)
    print((y).shape)
    return y*(1-y)
```

The dimensions of `y` are `20 X 10`. This function prints

`20 X 10
20 X 10`

And the function returns another matrix of dimension `20 X 10`.
In vector multiplication, the number of columns of the first argument must equal the number of rows of the 2nd argument. Even though this is not the case, how am I able to successfully execute this function?

Comment: Because `*` does not do matrix multiplication. Rather, it does elementwise multiplication. Try `numpy.dot` or the `@` operator if you have new enough python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Because * does not do matrix multiplication. Rather, it does elementwise multiplication. Try numpy.dot or the @ operator if you have new enough python." Provided by User: jme